# USB mouse stops working in Ubuntu 18.04, and it is not because of auto-suspend

Tags: usb, keyboard, 18.04, mouse

So, I have this problem since I was using 16.04. Today I updated to 18.04 in hope that fixes the problem (installed with erase everything).

I use my Huawei Android phone to connect to internet by USB tethering and it works fine.
But USB mouse(and keyboard) stops working after a while. I am really desperate for a solution, any help is appreciated!

Here is the part of syslog since the USB Huawei phone and then the mouse are detected till after the mouse stopped working.

```
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  253.995912] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.152923] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=107e
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.152925] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.152926] usb 1-4: Product: PRA-LA1
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.152927] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.152929] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: PSE7N17902000137
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.247752] usb-storage 1-4:1.1: USB Mass Storage device detected
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.249257] scsi host4: usb-storage 1-4:1.1
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.249356] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh kernel: [  254.263888] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh colord[982]: CdMain: failed to emit DeviceAdded: failed to register object: An object is already exported for the interface org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device at /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/sysfs__null_
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh gvfsd[1083]: Device 0 (VID=12d1 and PID=107e) is a Huawei P9 Plus.
Jul  4 11:53:23 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.260607] scsi 4:0:0:0: CD-ROM            Linux    File-CD Gadget   0401 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.261469] sr 4:0:0:0: Power-on or device reset occurred
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.262726] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] scsi-1 drive
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.262728] cdrom: Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.264386] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
Jul  4 11:53:24 Meh kernel: [  255.265519] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 5
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh gvfsd[1083]: Error 1: Get Storage information failed.
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating service name='org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh kernel: [  255.737850] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.HotplugSniffer'
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh kernel: [  255.907263] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh systemd[1]: Created slice system-clean\x2dmount\x2dpoint.slice.
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh systemd[1]: Started Clean the /media/obi/My CDROM mount point.
Jul  4 11:53:25 Meh udisksd[628]: Mounted /dev/sr0 at /media/obi/My CDROM on behalf of uid 1000
Jul  4 11:53:28 Meh colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  283.767916] usb 2-1: new low-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.163946] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=0005
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.163948] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.163949] usb 2-1: Product: USB Optical Mouse
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1"
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 2 was not an MTP device
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.221589] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.250255] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.250257] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.263622] input: USB Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001/input/input9
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh kernel: [  284.320019] hid-generic 0003:1BCF:0005.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [USB Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1/input0
Jul  4 11:53:53 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001
Jul  4 11:53:58 Meh colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  293.671126] usb 1-4: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh udisksd[628]: Cleaning up mount point /media/obi/My CDROM (device 11:0 no longer exists)
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh systemd[1]: Unmounting /media/obi/My CDROM...
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh gvfsd[1083]: PTP: reading event an error 0x05 occurred
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh udisksd[628]: Error cleaning up mount point /media/obi/My CDROM: Error unmounting: Command-line `umount -l "/media/obi/My CDROM"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /media/obi/My CDROM: not mounted.
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh udisksd[628]: Cleaning up mount point /media/obi/My CDROM (device 11:0 no longer exists)
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh systemd[1]: Unmounted /media/obi/My CDROM.
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh systemd[1]: Stopping Clean the /media/obi/My CDROM mount point...
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh systemd[1]: Stopped Clean the /media/obi/My CDROM mount point.
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.183931] usb 1-4: new high-speed USB device number 4 using ehci-pci
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.340875] usb 1-4: New USB device found, idVendor=12d1, idProduct=108a
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.340877] usb 1-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.340879] usb 1-4: Product: PRA-LA1
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.340880] usb 1-4: Manufacturer: HUAWEI
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh kernel: [  294.340881] usb 1-4: SerialNumber: PSE7N17902000137
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 4: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4"
Jul  4 11:54:03 Meh mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 4 was not an MTP device
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh kernel: [  294.444866] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_ether
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh kernel: [  294.457342] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:1d.7-4, RNDIS device, 0a:b6:be:67:a2:77
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh kernel: [  294.459074] usbcore: registered new interface driver rndis_host
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.0537] manager: (usb0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh systemd-udevd[1961]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.1
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh kernel: [  294.472347] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 enp0s29f7u4: renamed from usb0
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.0985] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/enp0s29f7u4, iface: enp0s29f7u4)
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.0985] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/enp0s29f7u4, iface: enp0s29f7u4): no ifupdown configuration found.
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh kernel: [  294.505275] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s29f7u4: link is not ready
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.0996] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1004] device (enp0s29f7u4): carrier: link connected
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1019] keyfile: add connection in-memory (c7e0d266-1f18-3bad-b81c-a7c3b24f9a87,"Wired connection 2")
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1049] settings: (enp0s29f7u4): created default wired connection 'Wired connection 2'
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1102] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1162] policy: auto-activating connection 'Wired connection 2'
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'bind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1221] device (enp0s29f7u4): Activation: starting connection 'Wired connection 2' (c7e0d266-1f18-3bad-b81c-a7c3b24f9a87)
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1283] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1313] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1458] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh gnome-shell[788]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js 97]: reference to undefined property 0
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh gnome-shell[788]: JS ERROR: TypeError: active.get_devices(...)[0] is undefined#012ensureActiveConnectionProps@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:97:22#012_getMainConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1814:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncMainConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832:32#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1483] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: JS WARNING: [resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js 97]: reference to undefined property 0
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: JS ERROR: TypeError: active.get_devices(...)[0] is undefined#012ensureActiveConnectionProps@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:97:22#012_getMainConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1814:13#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22#012_syncMainConnection@resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/status/network.js:1832:32#012wrapper@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82:22
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.1737] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698044.2364] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4): dhclient started with pid 1973
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh gvfsd[1083]: Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
Jul  4 11:54:04 Meh dhclient[1973]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp0s29f7u4 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x55dd2914)
Jul  4 11:54:05 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv6 with address fe80::1425:bf9:e568:9f60.
Jul  4 11:54:05 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: New relevant interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv6 for mDNS.
Jul  4 11:54:05 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: Registering new address record for fe80::1425:bf9:e568:9f60 on enp0s29f7u4.*.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh ModemManager[665]: <info>  Couldn't check support for device at '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-4': not supported by any plugin
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dhclient[1973]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.42.50 on enp0s29f7u4 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x1429dd55)
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dhclient[1973]: DHCPOFFER of 192.168.42.50 from 192.168.42.129
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dhclient[1973]: DHCPACK of 192.168.42.50 from 192.168.42.129
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8810] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   address 192.168.42.50
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8810] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8810] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   gateway 192.168.42.129
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8810] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   lease time 3600
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8811] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   hostname 'Meh'
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8811] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4):   nameserver '192.168.42.129'
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8811] dhcp4 (enp0s29f7u4): state changed unknown -> bound
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv4 with address 192.168.42.50.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: New relevant interface enp0s29f7u4.IPv4 for mDNS.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh avahi-daemon[670]: Registering new address record for 192.168.42.50 on enp0s29f7u4.IPv4.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8853] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh whoopsie[842]: [11:54:06] Cannot reach: https://daisy.ubuntu.com
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8874] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.8880] device (enp0s29f7u4): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.9027] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.9057] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.9058] policy: set 'Wired connection 2' (enp0s29f7u4) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530698046.9061] device (enp0s29f7u4): Activation: successful, device activated.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dbus-daemon[632]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.nm-dispatcher.service' requested by ':1.10' (uid=0 pid=652 comm="/usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh gsd-sharing[1222]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-user-share-webdav.service not loaded.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh gsd-sharing[1222]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit rygel.service not loaded.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh gsd-sharing[1222]: Failed to StopUnit service: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.NoSuchUnit: Unit gnome-remote-desktop.service not loaded.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dbus-daemon[632]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.nm_dispatcher'
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh systemd[1]: Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp0s29f7u4]: new request (1 scripts)
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh nm-dispatcher: req:1 'up' [enp0s29f7u4]: start running ordered scripts...
Jul  4 11:54:06 Meh dhclient[1973]: bound to 192.168.42.50 -- renewal in 1795 seconds.
Jul  4 11:54:07 Meh nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': new request (1 scripts)
Jul  4 11:54:07 Meh nm-dispatcher: req:2 'connectivity-change': start running ordered scripts...
Jul  4 11:54:07 Meh systemd-resolved[502]: Using degraded feature set (UDP) for DNS server 192.168.42.129.
Jul  4 11:54:08 Meh colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating service name='org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh systemd[1005]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating service name='org.gnome.Nautilus' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating service name='org.gnome.Calendar' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating service name='org.gnome.seahorse.Application' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.7' (uid=1000 pid=1110 comm="/usr/bin/gnome-shell " label="unconfined")
Jul  4 11:54:25 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.ControlCenter.SearchProvider'
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Nautilus'
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.seahorse.Application'
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh gnome-terminal-server[2065]: Display does not support owner-change; copy/paste will be broken!
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh systemd[1005]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
Jul  4 11:54:26 Meh dbus-daemon[1026]: [session uid=1000 pid=1026] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Calendar'
Jul  4 11:54:29 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: libinput error: client bug: timer event8 debounce: offset negative (-3ms)
Jul  4 11:54:29 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: libinput error: client bug: timer event8 debounce short: offset negative (-18ms)
Jul  4 11:54:29 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: setup_framebuffers: assertion 'width > 0' failed
Jul  4 07:54:32 Meh systemd-timesyncd[501]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jul  4 07:54:51 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: Received error from DBus search provider org.gnome.Software.desktop: Gio.IOErrorEnum: Timeout was reached
Jul  4 07:55:09 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530683709.0309] connectivity: (enp0s29f7u4) timed out
Jul  4 07:55:39 Meh snapd[674]: 2018/07/04 07:55:39 Unsolicited response received on idle HTTP channel starting with "HTTP/1.0 408 Request Time-out\r\nCache-Control: no-cache\r\nConnection: close\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n<html><body><h1>408 Request Time-out</h1>\nYour browser didn't send a complete request in time.\n</body></html>\n"; err=<nil>
Jul  4 07:55:43 Meh kernel: [  393.875100] perf: interrupt took too long (2512 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79500
Jul  4 07:55:51 Meh kernel: [  402.785163] TCP: enp0s29f7u4: Driver has suspect GRO implementation, TCP performance may be compromised.
Jul  4 07:56:16 Meh kernel: [  427.488183] perf: interrupt took too long (3146 > 3140), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
Jul  4 07:57:13 Meh kernel: [  484.298478] perf: interrupt took too long (3956 > 3932), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50500
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh kernel: [  601.184425] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: host controller process error, something bad happened!
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh kernel: [  601.184433] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: host controller halted, very bad!
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh kernel: [  601.184452] uhci_hcd 0000:00:1d.0: HC died; cleaning up
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh kernel: [  601.184486] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/0003:1BCF:0005.0001
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0
Jul  4 07:59:10 Meh upowerd[793]: unhandled action 'unbind' on /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1
Jul  4 07:59:15 Meh colord-sane: io/hpmud/pp.c 627: unable to read device-id ret=-1
Jul  4 07:59:31 Meh anacron[653]: Job `cron.weekly' started
Jul  4 07:59:31 Meh anacron[2425]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.weekly' to 2018-07-04
Jul  4 07:59:31 Meh kernel: [  622.519702] perf: interrupt took too long (4948 > 4945), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40250
Jul  4 07:59:34 Meh anacron[653]: Job `cron.weekly' terminated
Jul  4 08:00:09 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530684009.0308] connectivity: (enp0s29f7u4) timed out
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh gnome-software[1356]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: Object .Gjs_AppIndicatorIconActor__1 (0x555acfe00370), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it.
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: == Stack trace for context 0x555aceb02340 ==
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #0 0x7ffda96a9f80 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:83 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 87)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #1 0x555aceead710 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/indicatorStatusIcon.js:93 (0x7fd3400bf098 @ 58)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #2 0x7ffda96aab80 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #3 0x7ffda96aac40 b   self-hosted:915 (0x7fd3602f12b8 @ 367)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #4 0x7ffda96aad30 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fd3602d3230 @ 386)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #5 0x555aceead688 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/appIndicator.js:190 (0x7fd3400a8cd0 @ 22)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #6 0x7ffda96ab9a0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #7 0x555aceead5e0 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/statusNotifierWatcher.js:219 (0x7fd3400a8340 @ 225)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #8 0x7ffda96ac5a0 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #9 0x555aceead568 i   /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com/extension.js:61 (0x7fd34009a4d8 @ 37)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #10 0x555aceead4a8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:82 (0x7fd341e5a120 @ 431)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #11 0x555aceead428 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:344 (0x7fd341e5abc0 @ 13)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #12 0x7ffda96ad2c0 b   self-hosted:251 (0x7fd3602c3ab0 @ 223)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #13 0x555aceead3a8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:343 (0x7fd341e5ab38 @ 64)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #14 0x555aceead328 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/extensionSystem.js:361 (0x7fd341e5ac48 @ 87)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #15 0x7ffda96ae7e0 b   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/signals.js:128 (0x7fd3602d3230 @ 386)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #16 0x7ffda96aef80 b   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:205 (0x7fd341b6d670 @ 254)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #17 0x7ffda96afc80 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #18 0x555aceead1e8 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/sessionMode.js:167 (0x7fd341b6d450 @ 40)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #19 0x7ffda96b0880 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh gnome-software[1356]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #20 0x555aceead140 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:1280 (0x7fd341b50bc0 @ 188)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #21 0x7ffda96b1480 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #22 0x555aceead090 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:1329 (0x7fd341b50c48 @ 391)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #23 0x7ffda96b2080 I   resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/_legacy.js:82 (0x7fd3602b5de0 @ 71)
Jul  4 08:00:51 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: #24 0x555aceead010 i   resource:///org/gnome/shell/ui/screenShield.js:852 (0x7fd341b4fb38 @ 25)
Jul  4 08:04:23 Meh systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
Jul  4 08:04:23 Meh systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
Jul  4 08:05:09 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530684309.0310] connectivity: (enp0s29f7u4) timed out
Jul  4 08:07:40 Meh gnome-software[1356]: Only 0 apps for recent list, hiding
Jul  4 08:07:45 Meh PackageKit: resolve transaction /34_aeaedbda from uid 1000 finished with success after 5138ms
Jul  4 08:09:07 Meh gnome-software[1356]: no app for changed ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
Jul  4 08:09:07 Meh gnome-software[1356]: no app for changed ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com
Jul  4 08:09:07 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: [AppIndicatorSupport-DEBUG] Registering StatusNotifierItem :1.66/org/ayatana/NotificationItem/software_update_available
Jul  4 08:09:26 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: Some code accessed the property 'refreshPropertyOnProxy' on the module 'util'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
Jul  4 08:09:26 Meh update-notifier.desktop[1823]: /var/lib/dpkg/lock:
Jul  4 08:10:09 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530684609.0320] connectivity: (enp0s29f7u4) timed out
Jul  4 08:12:07 Meh org.gnome.Shell.desktop[1110]: libinput error: client bug: timer event3 debounce: offset negative (-32ms)
Jul  4 08:15:09 Meh NetworkManager[652]: <info>  [1530684909.0209] connectivity: (enp0s29f7u4) timed out
Jul  4 08:15:53 Meh gnome-shell[1110]: Some code accessed the property 'WindowPreviewMenu' on the module 'windowPreview'. That property was defined with 'let' or 'const' inside the module. This was previously supported, but is not correct according to the ES6 standard. Any symbols to be exported from a module must be defined with 'var'. The property access will work as previously for the time being, but please fix your code anyway.
```

Comment: what you mean? its already in askubuntu! should I move it t linux or something?

Comment: Ha sorry thought I was on stack overflow. It’s the iPhone app not immediately obvious to those not paying full attention.

Comment: The log show a disconnection and reconnection of the mouse and the phone. Can you reproduce the issue in a live system? It's possible that some device management configuration files left over from before the release upgrade interfere.

Comment: @DavidFoerster can you tell me what is a live system?

Comment: A live system is when you boot the Ubuntu installer and select the boot menu entry "Try Ubuntu".